# Re-entry to Germany after vacation using blue card

Tags: germany, international-travel

I am working in Germany and I hold a German blue card with a work permit. Now I am planning to travel to my home country for a short vacation (15-20 days). Should I clear/submit any other documents when I come back to Germany?

I am travelling back to my home country for the first time after obtaining blue card. That's why I have this doubt.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An German blue card is a residence permit issued in the EU uniform format. It looks like other German residence permits (that is, it's not physically very *blue*, though some of the background pattern is blue) except for the annotation `BLAUE KARTE EU`.

As a uniform-format residence card from a Schengen country, the card allows you to enter the Schengen area when you present it at the border, together with your valid passport or other travel document.

There shouldn't be a need for other documents. If you transit another Schengen country on your way to Germany, you *may* be asked to explain what you're doing there, but "I'm in transit towards Germany where I live" would be a fully sufficient answer to that.

Comment: I think all this confusion comes from the US system, where a few documents in addition to one's visa are sometimes required.

Comment: @JonathanReez: On the other hand if your have a US _green_ card, you don't even need a passport to enter, also in contrast to the EU blue card.

Comment: The US doesn't have a direct analog to the EU residence permit. The green card is only for _permanent_ residents, for instance. The EAD is a _work_ permit (and is good for entry if endorsed as I-512 advance parole). That might be the closest thing.